# Install Linux/Ubuntu in a Windows 8.1 machine

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, multi-boot

I recently have this notebook and make a fresh install of Windows 8.1, only one partitión of the complete disk, now I'd like to install Ubuntu or other Linux distro, do I have to format the hard drive and make the partitións for the OSEs, then install both or can I install ubuntu without reinstaling  w8.1 because I'm have a lot of programs installed and a lot of work in it.

Comment: You can shrink your windows partition by following this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309169.aspx. Then create a new partition and install linux. You do not have to format your existing windows 8.1. Ensure you have enough free space to do this.

Comment: You can also think about installing linux on a usb drive (pen drive or flash drive) and not touch your Windows at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Shrink Volume` feature of `Disk Management` to resize the existing partition and create new volumes, which you can use to install Ubuntu or any other OS.

Below are the steps you will be required to follow:

- Goto Disk Management (Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Computer Management->Disk Management)
- Right Click the drive and choose `Shrink Volume`
- Reboot and install Ubuntu

Detailed steps can be found [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/repartition-hard-disk#1TC=windows-7)

Note: You need to be logged in with Administrator account to be able to do this.